# Getting the description of the database with sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, turbogears

How can I find out the desciption of the database with sqlalchemy much like django's
sqlall command .

```
$ python manage.py sqlall
```

Can I run something similar to sqlall in turbogears admin or with sqlalchemy with which I can get the create table or something of all the current models.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [table reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#metadata-reflection) as well as the [inspector](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector).